# Issue in integration of Apache Atlas with Kerberized HBase and Solr

Tags: solr, hbase, apache-atlas

I am facing and issue related to the integration of Apache Atlas with Solr and HBase. I
have encountered an "Error 401 Authentication required" error when
attempting to update the vertex index in Solr, and I'm in need of guidance
and expertise to resolve this issue.

```
Apache Atlas version: apache-atlas-2.3.0

*Hbase version : 2.5.3 *
Solr version : 9.1.1
Kerberized Environment: Yes

# Authentication config
atlas.authentication.method=kerberos
atlas.authentication.keytab=/home/techuser/atlas/apache-atlas-2.3.0/keytabs/solr.keytab
atlas.authentication.principal=solr@HADOOP.COM
```

Could someone please offer their help in diagnosing and solving this authentication problem? We would greatly appreciate any insights, recommendations, or assistance you can provide. If you have experience with a similar issue or expertise in configuring Apache Atlas with Solr and HBase in a Kerberized environment, your input would be extremely valuable.